# Ag grid Enterprise agNumberCellEditor not working

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I am using Ag Grid enterprise and getting below error for inbuilt editors when I used for a column, any thoughts

```
{
  headerName: "Branches",
  field: "branches",
  width: 120,
  editable: true,
  cellEditor: 'agNumberCellEditor',
  cellEditorParams: {
    precision: 4,
  } 
}
```

AG Grid: Looking for component [agNumberCellEditor] but it wasn't found

Ag grid version : 28
Angular version :15

Comment: finally I figured out, it's an issue with Ag grid version, it's a brand new feature in latest version 30.   https://blog.ag-grid.com/whats-new-in-ag-grid-30/

Comment: Worked for me after upgrading as you suggested.Please log it as answer. Comments can be missed